# how to sort a array of name-value pair object using base array object

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have my main array as

```
var emaillist = [{"name":"harish","value":"varma"},
                 {"name":"ram","value":"john"},
                 {"name":"dam","value":"sam"},
            {"name":"james","value":"hope"}]
```

I have another modifiedemaillist array where value would be same but name will be different as above array

```
var modifiedemaillist =[{"name":"sam","value":"hope"},
          {"name":"hammy","value":"varma"}, 
             {"name":"nick","value":"john"}]
```

But in the second array the objects are not in sequence when compared to second array.

what is the easiest way to sort the second array using emaillist array based on value as it is common for both.

my modifiedemaillist should be as

```
[{"name":"hammy","value":"varma"},
 {"name":"nick","value":"john"}, 
 {"name":"sam","value":"hope"}]
```

Can someone please help on this!

Answer (score 0):

Use `.map` to turn the `emaillist` into an array containing only the `value`s, in order, then `.sort` the `modifiedemaillist` by comparing the `indexOf` each item in that ordered array:

```js
var emaillist = [{"name":"harish","value":"varma"},
                 {"name":"ram","value":"john"},
                 {"name":"dam","value":"sam"},
                 {"name":"james","value":"hope"}];
var values = emaillist.map(({ value }) => value);

var modifiedemaillist = [{"name":"sam","value":"hope"},
                         {"name":"hammy","value":"varma"}, 
                         {"name":"nick","value":"john"}];
modifiedemaillist.sort(
  (a, b) => values.indexOf(a.value) - values.indexOf(b.value)
);
console.log(modifiedemaillist);
```

Another option which will be slightly more performant would be to, instead of `.map`, create a `Map` whose keys are the `value`s and whose values are the index of the item in the original array. This will help because `Map.get` lookup time is generally `O(1)`, while `indexOf` is `O(N)`:

```js
var emaillist = [{"name":"harish","value":"varma"},
                 {"name":"ram","value":"john"},
                 {"name":"dam","value":"sam"},
                 {"name":"james","value":"hope"}];
var values = new Map(
  emaillist.map(({ value }, i) => ([value, i]))
);

var modifiedemaillist = [{"name":"sam","value":"hope"},
                         {"name":"hammy","value":"varma"}, 
                         {"name":"nick","value":"john"}];
modifiedemaillist.sort(
  (a, b) => values.get(a.value) - values.get(b.value)
);
console.log(modifiedemaillist);
```

Comment: You can use Object.values(object) instead of using the map function

Comment: The `emaillist` is already an array - it's not an object, `Object.values` won't help

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the index of the object in the first array based on the `value` property to get that second array sorted:

```js
var emaillist = [{
    "name": "harish",
    "value": "varma"
  },
  {
    "name": "ram",
    "value": "john"
  },
  {
    "name": "dam",
    "value": "sam"
  },
  {
    "name": "james",
    "value": "hope"
  }
];

var modifiedemaillist = [{
    "name": "sam",
    "value": "hope"
  },
  {
    "name": "hammy",
    "value": "varma"
  },
  {
    "name": "nick",
    "value": "john"
  }
];

modifiedemaillist.sort(function(a, b){
  var indexA = emaillist.findIndex(({value}) => value === a.value);
  var indexb = emaillist.findIndex(({value}) => value === b.value);
  return indexA - indexb;
});
console.log(modifiedemaillist);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store the indices for the values and take the delta of the inidces as sort value.

For unknown `value`, you could take `Infinity` as default value and take an incremented index values as mapping value (to prevent zero triggering the default value).

```js
var emaillist = [{ name: "harish", value: "varma" }, { name: "ram", value: "john" }, { name: "dam", value: "sam" }, { name: "james", value: "hope" }],
    modifiedemaillist = [{ value: "unknown1" }, { name: "sam", value: "hope" }, { value: "unknown2" }, { name: "hammy", value: "varma" }, { name: "nick", value: "john" }],
    order = emaillist.reduce((m, { value }, i) => m.set(value, i + 1), new Map);
             
modifiedemaillist.sort(({ value: a }, { value: b }) => (order.get(a) || Infinity) - (order.get(b) || Infinity));

console.log(modifiedemaillist);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: hi @nina .Suppose in my second array if i have an object whose value does'nt match to any  one from first array.It should be added at last depending on number of such objects in sequence.But your code is not working in such case.how can we handle such case

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to loop through source array and push to result values, that second array contains, then add the rest

```
const sort = (arr1, arr2) => {
  const res = [];
  arr1.forEach(v => {
    const toPush = arr2.find(w => w.value === v.value);
    if (toPush)
      res.push(toPush);
  });
  return [...res, ...arr2.filter(w => res.every(v => v.value !== w.value))];
}
```